# How to read image bytes in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to display image in jsp page for that i am using bellow code.Everything was fine but some error was displayed and i don't know how to fix this can any one help me to fix this.

**code:**

```
  <%@page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
InputStream inStream = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
BufferedImage bImage=null;

inStream = new FileInputStream("/home/anand/Desktop/encrypt/firstBG.jpg");
bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
int numByte = bis.available();
byte[] buf = new byte[numByte];
bis.read(buf, 2, 3);


 bImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));//give the path of an image
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( bImage, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
String b64 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
%>

<div>
    <p>As of v6, Java SE provides JAXB</p>
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <%=b64%>" alt="Visruth.jpg not found" />
</div>          
</body>
</html>
```

**error**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/get] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /NewFile2.jsp at line 27

24: 
25:  bImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));//give the path of an image
26: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
27: ImageIO.write( bImage, "jpg", baos );
28: baos.flush();
29: byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
30: baos.close();


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1578)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile2_jsp._jspService(NewFile2_jsp.java:90)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know the problem is writing bytes in BufferedImage but i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: What's this: `bis.read(buf, 2, 3);` ?? Reading 3 bytes only, at offset 2? Why? That's almost certainly wrong.

Comment: What don't you read directly from the file with ImageIO? `bImage = ImageIO.read(inStream);`

Comment: And why do you even use ImageIO? The file is already available in a JPG format, it's in `"/home/anand/Desktop/encrypt/firstBG.jpg"`: no need to read and then write it with ImageIO.